# How to concat bunch of arrays inside and object

Tags: javascript

I been searching for 3 hours and couldnt find an answer. The only think i can think of is to use for loop and push each element.

How i got this problem. I fetched some charges, each charge has an array of items. So I map the charge and returned the array items but It gave me this.

Example

```
let object = [
[{id:1},{id:2}],
[{id:3},{id:4}],
[{id:5},{id:6}]
]
```

What i am looking for :

```
object =[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5},{id:6}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) as follows:

```js
const object = [
  [{id:1},{id:2}],
  [{id:3},{id:4}],
  [{id:5},{id:6}]
];

const res = object.flat();

console.log(res);
```

If `object` here is a result of mapping, [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) might be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, You can use concat to merge arrays:

```js
let objects = [
[{id:1},{id:2}],
[{id:3},{id:4}],
[{id:5},{id:6}]
];
objects = [].concat.apply([], objects);
```

or use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control)

```js
objects = objects.reduce(function(a, b){
     return a.concat(b);
}, []);
```

with arrow function ES2015

```js
objects = objects.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
```